# Configure FluentNHibernate, FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly; meaning

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

The line

```
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>()
```

What does it do? Will it look for any class in the assembly of the Product class that derives from the ClassMap ? Or what is the logic behind? Can I just put any random class of that assembly here and expect it to find all mapping classes in this assembly?

```
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    { 
          return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(Properties.Settings.Default.FnhDbString)
            .Cache(c => c
                .UseQueryCache()).ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Product>()
            .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always thought that when you use `AddFromAssemblyOf`, fluent will try to map EVERY class in the assembly.

Therefore you just need to add a class (any one) from an assembly that contains your ClassMap.

Additional from the [fluent wiki](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration)

> ..it then adds any fluent mappings from
>   the assembly that contains YourEntity

Comment: You can also chain together a `Where()` method after that to specify some criteria the class must meet.

Comment: Ok. So I assume that means not "every class", but every class implementing ClassMap<T> (?)

Comment: I don't know the internals of Fluent-NHibernate but I suspect it enumerates its way through all classes and only returns those that implement ClassMap<T>.